# Why does an allocated 2-dimensional int array have a different sequence of memory addresses as a normal one?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

The following code outputs the sequence of memory addresses of a dynamically allocated array, then a regular 2D array (of ints) via nested for loops.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int regArray[3][3]; //a normal 2d array
    int **allocatedArray = new int*[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        allocatedArray[i] = new int[3]; //an allocated 2d array


    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            cout << &allocatedArray[i][j] << "    " << &regArray[i][j] << endl; 
            //prints the allocated array, leaves a space, then a regular one
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
0x7812e8    0x29febc
0x7812ec    0x29fec0
0x7812f0    0x29fec4
0x781300    0x29fec8
0x781304    0x29fecc
0x781308    0x29fed0
0x781318    0x29fed4
0x78131c    0x29fed8
0x781320    0x29fedc

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.249 s
Press any key to continue.
```

I know that in the regular array (right side), the next element's address results in an increase of 4 bytes (in hexadecimal form). However, in the allocated array (left side) this does not seem to be the case. During the execution of the inner for loop, there is a normal increase of 4 bytes, as expected. Whenever the outer loop iterates, there seems to be an increase of 10.

An example is when: 0x7812f0 jumps to 0x781300.

Why does this occur? Any simple explanation is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your arrays are allocated. But they use different forms of allocation (*automatic* and *dynamic* respectively).

Your first array places 9 ints in 9 consecutive memory locations.

Your second array allocates three separate blocks of 3 consecutive memory locations. Those 3 blocks could be anywhere, they do not have to be next to each other in memory.

Your output confirms this.

Comment: Does this mean that those 3 blocks of memory don't necessarily have to be 10 bytes apart?

Comment: The 0x10 byte difference is very likely the size of the header for heap allocated blocks. The allocator will store information like the address of next block and size of block, maybe debugging flags, etc.

Comment: @54skyx that's right, in your case it just happened this way because of details about how your particular system's dynamic allocator works. In general there could be no relationship.

Comment: Maybe we can allocate a 100 * 100 array and check if they're all 10 bytes ;)

Answer (score 0):

The code below means to allocate a pointer to a pointer array

```
int **allocatedArray = new int*[3];
```

and here is to make each of the pointer a allocated array

```
allocatedArray[i] = new int[3];
```

The code above allocates a int array which should be 12 bytes, but between each 2 of the 1-dimensional array have no relationship.

So, the size of `allocatedArray[i][j]` is 4 bytes
and `allocatedArray[i]` is 12 bytes

the 10 bytes you mentioned is just a coincidence